# How to get swagger json separately?

Tags: json, rest, jax-rs, swagger, swagger-2.0

I try to generate swagger.json from my java rest endpoints.

**pom**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Applicationpath**

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestApplication extends Application {
    public RestApplication() {
        BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        //beanConfig.setVersion("1.0");
        beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[] { "http" });
        beanConfig.setTitle("My API");
        beanConfig.setBasePath("/rest");
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage("com.test.rest");
        beanConfig.setScan(true);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        HashSet<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

        set.add(com.test.AddressEndpoint.class);
        set.add(com.test.ATGEndpoint.class);
        set.add(com.test.CompanyEndpoint.class)

        set.add(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.class);
        set.add(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers.class);

        return set;
    }
}
```

**AddressEndpoint**

```
@Api
@Singleton
@Path("/Addresss")
@Produces("application/json")
@ConcurrencyManagement
@Lock(LockType.READ)
public class AddressEndpoint {

private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AddressEndpoint.class.getName());

@Context
private HttpRequest httpRequest;

@Inject
AddressService AddressService;
/**
* @description creates a new Address 
* @status 400 Address country cannot be null
* @status 400 Address address2 cannot be null
* @status 400 Address city cannot be null
* @status 400 Address address1 cannot be null
* @status 400 Address postcode cannot be null
* @status 400 Address id cannot be null
* @status 400 Address state cannot be null
* @status 201 Address created successfully
*/
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response create(Address entity) {
    AddressService.insert(entity);
    return Response.created(UriBuilder.fromResource(AddressEndpoint.class).path(String.valueOf(entity.getId())).build()).build();
}
```

...

When i deploy my testdbwar in wildfly,
I try to access my json like;
**`http://localhost:8080/testdbwar/rest/swagger.json?`**

And i get a big json which contains all jsons .

1. How can I get json separately for each endpoint?
2. Can i get them generated locally in a file system?
3. The big json file loads the UI at once. I would like to have separate links for each endpoint type.

Comment: What is the Java framework you are using? or Can you post any link if any, you followed to configure Swagger?

Comment: @SupunWijerathne io.swagger library

Comment: No. What I asked was the application framework, ex: Spring MVC, Play etc.?

Comment: @SupunWijerathne its jaxrs REST service (war) deployed in jboss

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the 'artifactId' properly @ first sight.

Answer (score 0):

1. Generally for any swagger library, it is `all_resource_listing_url/pathName`. When I googled for jax-rs, [this](http://jmchung.github.io/blog/2013/12/14/integrating-swagger-into-jax-rs-with-java-ee-6-specification/) is one I found somewhat related to your problem though that was with wordnik.swagger library. In your case, it should be `http://localhost:8080/testdbwar/rest/swagger.json/Addresss` for apis listed under path `'Addresss'`. I don't know, whether you misspelled 'Addresss' with 'sss' and tried with 'ss' already. And please also try with a  lower-case path name.
2. I don't think there's an automated way with swagger configuration itself. But You can do that manually with a small-code right? Anyway It looks like, that kind of a support is available there with some commercial tools like [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZFB2_3.0.1/com.ibm.apimgmt.apionprem.doc/tapim_api_swagger_download.html).
3. A solution for Q1 is applicable to this one too, right? Inside the swagger-ui, you can invoke the swagger doc urls differently for each different paths.